# Calculating Odds Ratio between multiple columns of a dataframe

Tags: r

I have the following dataframe:

```
structure(list(id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 
13, 14, 15), var1 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1), var2 = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1), 
    var3 = c(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1), var4 = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1), outcome = c(1, 
    1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)), row.names = c(NA, 
-15L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I would like to arrange a script to calculate all possible odds ratio (using chi square), with 95% CI and p values, between all columns and the column outcome.
How can I do that?

I installed epitools but it seems that I need a 2x2 contingency table and I am not able to apply the function to columns of a dataframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `mapply`, you can use the `fisher.test` function, which doesn't fail when the odds ratio cannot be calculated.

```
mapply(fisher.test, x=data[, grep("var", names(data))], y=data[,"outcome"])
```

But the output is a 7x4 matrix which cannot be tidied into a nice format. However, we can use `lapply` to perform Fisher's test for each column and then tidy the results with the **broom** package.

```
library(broom)

cols <- df1[,grep("var", names(df1))]
res_list <- lapply(as.list(cols), function(x) fisher.test(x, y=df1$outcome))
do.call(rbind, lapply(res_list, broom::tidy))

# A tibble: 4 x 6
  estimate p.value conf.low conf.high method                alternative
     <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl> <chr>                 <chr>      
1     0      1        0          77.9 Fisher's Exact Test ~ two.sided  
2   Inf      0.505    0.204     Inf   Fisher's Exact Test ~ two.sided  
3     2.13   0.608    0.160      37.2 Fisher's Exact Test ~ two.sided  
4   Inf      0.505    0.204     Inf   Fisher's Exact Test ~ two.sided
```

Or using **dplyr** with `map`, reshaping first and then splitting on the name.

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>%
  pivot_longer(cols=starts_with("var")) %>%
  split(.$name) %>%
  map(~fisher.test(x=.$value, y=.$outcome)) %>%
  map(tidy) %>%
  map_df(~as_tibble(.))
```

---

**Data**:

```
df1 <- structure(list(id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 
13, 14, 15), var1 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1), var2 = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1), 
    var3 = c(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1), var4 = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1), outcome = c(1, 
    1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)), row.names = c(NA, 
-15L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code performs the computations as described in the question but 3/4 give errors.

```
library(epitools)

cols <- grep("var", names(df1), value = TRUE)
res_list <- lapply(cols, function(v){
  tbl <- table(df1[, c(v, "outcome")])
  tryCatch(oddsratio(x = tbl), error = function(e) e)
})

ok <- !sapply(res_list, inherits, "error")
res_list[ok]
```

The errors are all this:

> simpleError in uniroot(function(or) {    1 - midp(a1, a0, b1, b0, or)
>   - alpha/2}, interval = interval): f() values at end points not of opposite sign

which can be seen with

```
res_list[!ok]
```